# url redirecting through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i have hosted two sites on same server and i mange them giving folders for each domain. i want to site comes as

```
example.com/example
example1.com/example1
```

i want to come

```
example.com and example.com
```

i come to know that htaccess url redirecting can do this but i have less idea about it.
if there is some tutorial on php regular expression please let me know.
some help is appreciable.

**edited**
i solved this problem by putting .htaccess file in root and writing:

```
RewriteEngine On
#for example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /example/$1 [L]
```

when i hit example.com it works fine now. it access the folder /example. but i had a problem on a certain domain. i m using codeigniter and i have to redirect its request also so that it does not show

```
example.com/example/index.php/controller/
```

i want to show this:

```
example.com/controller/
```

hope some experts can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .htaccess url redirecting is setup as a file in your main directory and your code can look something like this:

```
 # These redirects should do the trick :-)
 Redirect example.com/example http://www.example.com
 Redirect example.com/example1 http://www.example.com
```